# Dynamic Javascript appending with location.href attribute and ajax-cross-domain.com script

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

After assigning this: window.onload = initfunction;

I want to append the AJAX cross domain script to the header:

```
function initfunction() {
 var dh = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var script = null;
 script = document.createElement('script');
 script.setAttribute('src', 'http://whatever.com/cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?'+location.href);
 script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
 dh.appendChild(script);
  }
```

The script seems to be appended with the correct domain name, but Firebug says: "Failed to load source". If I type a fixed URL within the src attribute it works! e.g.:

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://whatever.com/cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?http://google.com');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried alerting location.href? Does is give you the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i got the solution. The problem was not the "location.href" itself, but a **rule in our firewall** that prohibits a GET request to the own server. Therefore the script throwed a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about ajax-cross-domain.com's script, shouldn't it be:

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://whatever.com/cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?uri=('+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+')');
```

Comment: That's right, but i simplified the script (cut the uri= stuff and so on). However, with a fixed URI it works!

Comment: Have you included the proper uri=... version inside `@allowed_uris`?

Comment: Also, what's the real URL you're trying to use? Fetching the current page (`location.href`) through an ACD proxy makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: It makes sense in my case. I want to provide a special service to webmasters. therefore i need the cross domain stuff. to simplify the script inclusion for webmasters i have to use location.href and block not allowed uris from within ACD.

Comment: Erm. But the current page is already quite readable from JavaScript, there is no need to send a request to your server proxying to their server to return a page that's already loaded in the browser.

Comment: hehe in this case you're right. but we're doing some changes to the html content and afterwards sending it back to the browser, were it is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified code snippet for test purposes. Just put this as an onload function or a script tag in the header. the webpage will continuously load...

```
var dh = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if(!dh)
{
  //html page without "head"
  head = document.createElement('head');
  document.appendChild(head);
}
var script = null;
script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://domain.com/cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?' + location.href);
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
dh.appendChild(script);
```